# Editing Quirks for a USB driver

Tags: usb, driver

I have a device which is using the usbhid driver.

I noticed a module folder inside the driver with a file name quirks.Can anyone tell me the correct way to edit this file and the values it can take?

```
    root@raspberrypi:/sys/bus/hid/drivers/generic-usb/module/parameters# dir
    ignoreled  mousepoll  quirks
```

By default it only contains the following value.

```
    (null),(null),(null),(null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can find a list by module with modinfo

```
$ modinfo usbhid
...
parm:           quirks:Add/modify USB HID quirks by specifying  quirks=vendorID:productID:quirks where vendorID, productID, and quirks are all in 0x-prefixed hex (array of charp)
```

And you can give them as parameters while loading a module.

```
$ sudo modprobe -v usbhid "quirks=0xDEAD:0xBEEF:0x55AA"
```

I believe you can also just write these into a sysfs file at runtime in some cases. Seems the usbhid is read-only on my (desktop) system, though.

```
$ echo "0xDEAD:0xBEEF:0x55AA" | sudo tee -a /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/quirks
tee: /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/quirks: Permission denied
```

I haven't looked into these more and you'll need to find the actual values from somewhere (source, LXR?), but maybe that's a start.

Comment: The answer was really helpful.I was able to add quirks to the driver using the first method.Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: @SteveIrwin where did you find the description for the quirks? I looked at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/hid.h#L317 which is where they are `#defined`, unfortunately there is no description for them. Are the quirks names assumed to be descriptive enough? Or did you find any detailed info on each of them? If so could you point me to this info.

Answer (score 4):

A real world example that I use

```
cat /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks
0bc2:3312:u,0bc2:ab38:u
```

Note that the format is `vendor:device:flag[,...]` and that `,` not `\n` must be used for multiple devices.
There is a list of valid flags in the source [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ead751507de86d90fa250431e9990a8b881f713c/drivers/usb/storage/usb.c#L527).